# NSDateFormatter returns nil in a simply date format change

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert this date:

```
Jun 23, 2015 7:53:04 PM
```

coming from a server response, to a different format using `NSDateFormatter` but it is constantly returning `nil` and `(null)` values in the console if I try to NSLog it. The code I'm using to do so is the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[contentData valueForKey:@"startDate"]];
```

Isn't `MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a` the correct format to parse the date?

**UPDATE**

I changed the code in the following way:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Jun 23, 2015 7:53:04 PM"];
```

But it still doesn't work

Comment: date format `MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a`

Comment: It still doesn't work :-/

Comment: And... it still doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Jun 23, 2015 7:53:04 PM"];
NSLog(@"date: %@",date);//date: 2015-06-23 13:53:04 +0000
NSString* formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Formatted Date: %@",formattedDate);//Formatted Date: Jun 23, 2015 07:53:04 PM
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work :-/ I don't know why

Comment: Still a nil value :-/

Comment: in my case i get this result. i also use same xcode 7.0 and ios 9.0